# "in Beispiel (a) ..." – warum nicht "im Beispiel (a) ..."?

Tags: article

In wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten sehe ich oft:

> Wie bereits **in** Abschnitt 1 gezeigt, …
>
> **In** Beleg (2) …
>
> **In** Satzbeispiel (3) …
>
> Auf Seite 4 …

Warum nicht **im** oder **auf der** Seite? Warum wird der Artikel ausgelassen? Ist es der Einfluss der Zahl?

Comment: Das ist schlichtweg ungrammatisch, aber schwer auszurotten.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach handelt es sich hier um *Maßangaben*, die ebenfalls ohne Artikel auskommen dürfen, analog zu *Bei Kilometer 30 auf der B2 ereignete sich...*.  Wenn durch die Kapitelnummer die Position schon exakt bestimmt ist, ist ein bestimmter Artikel redundant (es gibt ja nur eines, das Kapitel wird dadurch auch nicht "bestimmter") und ein unbestimmter Artikel falsch.

Comment: @Janka Wenn es so häufig vorkommt, kann es höchstens nach einer präskriptiven Vorschrift ungrammatisch sein, nicht nach Sprachgefühl. Nach welcher denn?

Comment: Der Dativ wird unterschlagen, man muss ihn sich denken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deutsche Nomen brauchen grundsätzlich einen Artikel - genauer: *Determiner*, denn es kann auch ein Possessivpronomen, Demonstrativpronomen o.ä. sein: *das Beispiel*, *dein Beispiel*, *dieses Beispiel*.

Es gibt verschiedene Ausnahmen davon, z.B. für Stoffnomen (*Wasser*). Eine davon ist die zusätzliche Bestimmung durch einen Index:

> Wir haben Ihnen das Zimmer reserviert.
>   Wir haben Ihnen ein Zimmer reserviert.
>   Wir haben Ihnen dieses Zimmer reserviert.
>
> <del>Wir haben Ihnen Zimmer reserviert.</del>
>
> Wir haben Ihnen Zimmer 101 reserviert.
>   Wir haben Ihnen das Zimmer 101 reserviert.

Ausdrücke wie "Zimmer 101", "Paragraph 26a" oder "Akte ZX-30" können mit *oder* ohne Artikel stehen. Im Sprachgebrauch ist die Form ohne Artikel vielleicht sogar etwas häufiger.